# How to add enum image source to React-native-circle-button?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to add a custom image source to the attribute iconButtonCenter in the React Native library named react-native-circle-button. 
https://github.com/dwicao/react-native-circle-button

According to the documentation, iconButtonCenter is of type enum, so I imported the icon and then passed it in directly where I create my CircleButton object. It does not yell as if it is a number or string, yet I still am not 100% sure it is technically of type enum. I know for a fact it is finding the image in the right path. I also know that it is doing something, because the default image is no longer observable on the app, it just no longer has an icon. I am not getting any compilation errors or warning, yet I still do not see the icon appear over the button as it should. How do I fix this?

Here is the render within my component that allows circle button's to be draggable. I also went ahead and put my import at the top so you can see how this was stored.

```
import letterA  from '../assets/letters/alpha-a.svg';

render() {
    let { pan } = this.state;

    let [translateX, translateY] = [pan.x, pan.y];

    let moveableStyle = {transform: [{translateX}, {translateY}]};
    const panStyle = {
      transform: this.state.pan.getTranslateTransform()
    }
    return (
      <Animated.View
        {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
        style={[moveableStyle, panStyle]}>
          <CircleButton iconButtonCenter={letterA} /> <--- Here is the image source reference.
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
```

The CircleButton component should successfully have the image fed to it and remain centered over the button even when dragged along the string.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was the picture format was an .svg, converting the icons to .png worked like a charm!